# Find the missing entities from a list of entities

Tags: java

I would like to get a list of maps that being grouped by `year` and find missing Students based on a list of studentNo.

```
class Student {
   private String studentNo
   private String studentName
   private String year

   // Getter is implemented
   // Setter is implemented
}

List<String> studnetNoList = new ArrayList<>();

studnetNoList = 
 [
    "001A",
    "002B",
    "003C"
 ]
```

This is the sample list of students

```
List<Student> studentList = new ArrayList<>();
    
studentList = 
    [
      {
        "studentNo": "001A",
        "studentName": "Alex",
        "year": "2010"
      },
      {
        "studentNo": "001B",
        "studentName": "John",
        "year": "2010"
      },
      {
        "studentNo": "003C",
        "studentName": "Jane",
        "year": "2011"
      },
      {
        "studentNo": "001A",
        "studentName": "David",
        "year": "2011"
      },
      {
        "studentNo": "001C",
        "studentName": "Jane",
        "year": "2012"
      }
    ]


HashMap<String, Student> groupedStudent = new HashMap<>();

{
  "2010": [
    {
      "studentNo": "001A",
      "studentName": "Alex",
      "year": "2010"
    },
    {
      "studentNo": "001B",
      "studentName": "John",
      "year": "2010"
    }
  ],
  "2011": [
    {
      "studentNo": "003C",
      "studentName": "Jane",
      "year": "2011"
    },
    {
      "studentNo": "001A",
      "studentName": "David",
      "year": "2011"
    }
  ],
  "2012": [
    {
      "studentNo": "001C",
      "studentName": "Jane",
      "year": "2012"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my expected result of a list

```
List<Student> missingStudentList = new ArrayList<>();

{
  "2010": [
    {
      "studentNo": "001C",
      "studentName": "Jane",
      "year": "2010"
    }
  ],
  "2011": [
    {
      "studentNo": "001B",
      "studentName": "John",
      "year": "2011"
    }
  ],
  "2012": [
    {
      "studentNo": "001A",
      "studentName": "Alex",
      "year": "2010"
    },
    {
      "studentNo": "001B",
      "studentName": "John",
      "year": "2010"
    }
  ]
}
```

> I just solved the question!!
>
> First of all, I grouped the original student list by year into a map, then
> I iterate this map of a grouped students with the list of student
> numbers to find the missing students. Then I had to recreate the
> `Student` by setting a new value of `year` which needs to be specified for a student, I never thought of setting a new value of
> `year` for Student. That was the reason why I got stuck in finding
> missing Students.
>
> I've got a lot of assistance from this community! Thanks all!!

Comment: Could you please put compliable code as post please? It takes too long to convert it to something we can work with.

Comment: I just solved the question!! thanks for your reply thou!!